# Nuxt read module state inside a component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I've got a Nuxt application with a `store` directory that resembles this folder
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#example-folder-structure.

Imagine that I have a property `isComplete` in my module state inside the `cart` folder.

I get the following error that `Property 'shop' does not exist on type 'RootState'.`

How could I access this property in a Vue component ?

`Component.vue`

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import { useStore } from '~/store'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Component',
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()

    onMounted(() => {
      if (store.state.shop.cart.isComplete) {
        // Execute some code
      }
    })
  },
})
</script>
```

My `store/index.ts` has the following implementation

```
import { InjectionKey, useStore as baseUseStore } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export interface RootState {}

export const state = () => ({})

export const injectionKey: InjectionKey<RootState> =
  Symbol('vuex-injection-key')

export const useStore = () => {
  return baseUseStore(injectionKey)
}
```

`store/shop/cart/state.ts`

```
export interface CartState {
  isComplete: boolean
}

export const state = (): CartState => ({
  isComplete: false,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Store state

Store files named `state` should have an object-returning method as its default export, so `store/shop/cart/state.ts` should contain `export default state` (where `state` is the method) as its last line. Otherwise, you'll see a warning in the browser console:

> ```
> store/shop/cart/state.ts should export a method that returns an object
> ```

Or you could rename `store/shop/cart/state.ts` to `store/shop/cart/index.ts` (perhaps the original intent based on the exported `state` constant).

### `RootState` type

There's no type inference available here, so the `RootState` needs to be explicitly typed to include the states of modules.

1. Import the `CartState` from the namespaced module.
2. Add a key named after each namespaced module, nested as needed (i.e., `shop` and then `cart`). Apply the `CartState` type for the `cart` key.

```js
// store/index.ts
import type { CartState } from './shop/cart' 1️⃣

export interface RootState {
  shop: {
    cart: CartState, 2️⃣
  }
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/nuxt-typing-store-modules)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works as needed! However, I've created a `store/shop/cart/mutations.ts` that I import inside `store.shop/cart/state.ts`. This `mutations.ts` exports a `mutations` object that contains each mutation method. However, I get the error `[vuex] unknown mutation type: MY_MUTATION`. The exported object has the type `MutationTree<CartState>`. Do I have to import the module mutations in the `store/index.ts`?

Comment: I inspected the `store` and it seems like the export mutation name is wrong :) `store/cart/MY_MUTATION` instead of `MY_MUTATION`